# How can I get the IP of an HTTP request in a Laravel Vapor application?

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, laravel-vapor

I recently moved a Laravel app from a server to Vapor. This app relies on logging request IP addresses using `Request::ip()`, but since switching to Vapor, all IPs are logged as 127.0.0.1.

I have looked over the Trusted Proxy docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies but we do not have a load balancer set up, so this solution does not appear relevant. I suspect this IP address is coming from the Amazon API Gateway.

How do we get the *actual* client IP of incoming requests in an app deployed on Vapor?

A minimal example of how we use the IP address is below:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $workerIP = $request->ip();
        $worker = Worker::create(['ip_address' => $workerIP]);
        return view('workers.show')->withWorker($worker);

    }
```

Comment: Hi! I think you tagged the wrong Vapor. The one you tagged is for the Swift framework https://vapor.codes/

Comment: @TWOF is there actually a Laravel Vapor tag?

Comment: @Nathan There is now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"we do not have a load balancer set up" Yes, you do. The API Gateway is, fundamentally, a proxy of exactly the sort that the trusted proxy configuration is intended for.

Set `'proxies' => '*'` in your `config/trustedproxy.php` file and you should start seeing the right IP addresses.

Comment: This does not work in Laravel Vapor as there are two proxies before the lambda (API Gateway and Cloudfront). I have not figured out any way to retrieve the client's ip securely.

Comment: @mikkokut I'd hit up Vapor support. Chains of `X-Forwarded-For` headers should work fine, but with Vapor being new it's possible they don't have it configured exactly right yet.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy/issues/107

Answer (score 13):

There is `x-vapor-source-ip` header in latest Vapor core package (vapor-core:v2.2.1) which exposes Lambda's `sourceIp` property in order to get the client's real ip safely.

You can retrieve the ip:

```
Request::header('x-vapor-source-ip')
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Not sure why this isn't included in the official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. The suggested `x-vapor-source-ip` does not work when CloudFlare is being used like when you use Vapors temporary URL's. When Laravel Vapor sits behind CloudFlare, the User's IP address can be obtained via:

`$request->header('cf-connecting-ip');`

On actual domain names (non Vapor domains) use:

`$request->header('x-vapor-source-ip');`

Answer (score 1):

I talked to Vapor Support today. They told me to keep TrustProxy default value and let Vapor does the magic. It works. This is my TrustProxy

```
class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
/**
 * The trusted proxies for this application.
 *
 * @var array|string
 */
protected $proxies;

/**
 * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

and to get IP, I m using `request()->ip()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the client IP which application is accessing.

then you will check the **$_SERVER** you will get more information there.

```
 $_SERVER['HTTP_X_VAPOR_SOURCE_IP']
```

try out above variable there you get your client ip. also below helper function in Laravel help you to get IP.

```
function get_client_ip()
{
  $ipaddress = '';
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
  else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_VAPOR_SOURCE_IP']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_VAPOR_SOURCE_IP'];
  else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
  else if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
  return $ipaddress;
}
```

You can tried this function. Thanks.